# Colors in C++ win32 console

Tags: c++

```
std::cout << "blblabla... [done]" << std::endl;
```

Is it possible to make `[done]` be in another color, and possibly bold? I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 21):

This depends on which OS you are using.

If you're using windows you want [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047(VS.85).aspx):

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // Get handle to standard output
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

You can also combine values.

> An application can combine the
>   foreground and background constants to
>   achieve different colors. For example,
>   the following combination results in
>   bright cyan text on a blue background.
>
> FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN |
>   FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_BLUE

You can then use [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(VS.85).aspx) or [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401(VS.85).aspx) to actually write the the console.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you just send a [standard escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g.

```
    const char* green = "\033[0;32m";
    const char* white = "\033[0;37m";
    const char* red   = "\033[0;31m";
    double profit = round(someComplicatedThing());
    std::cout << (profit < 0 ? red : (profit > 0 ? green : white))
              << "Profit is " << profit << white << std::endl;
```

You also get bold vs normal, colored background etc. The [Wikipedia page on ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) has details, the [Bash-Prompt HOWTO](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html) has examples.

Comment: Don't forget to document how to get ANSI.SYS loaded, it isn't automatic.

Answer (score 4):

[You can use this tiny libraries which I have used personally before](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/AddColorConsole.aspx). It is very easy to use and integrate with standard streams. It has a clear console screen functionality btw. This example is from a code I wrote:

```
    std::cout << con::clr; // Clear the Intro Screen
// fg means the foreground
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << con::fg_green
    << "\t\tFile Encrypted!";
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can you can use the system(); function to run commands from the command.com and one of those is color.
color a will get you the green you want.
you may also see other colors from the help option color /? .
and for the bold thing you can use characters from ascii chart to do that.
such as "\n" Is Newline.

Answer (score -5):

A quick way: include `#include <stdlib.h>` and then add `system( "color 5B" );` before the text you want. So it will look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
std::cout << "blblabla..."<<std::endl;
system( "color 5B" );
std::cout<< "[done]" << std::endl;
```

You can try different colors: 1A, 2B, 3C, 4F...